# Logic for filter using ETL- (Matillion or Python)

Tags: python, sql, etl, matillion

Data set:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blSLb.png)

```
email   brand   startdate   response_no     need logic for conditions to select/filter response
abc     wi      4/1/2019     1              (select)
abc     wi      9/4/2019     2           (compare with 1st),since less than 6 month, filter out)
abc     wi      11/22/2019   3           (compare with 1st), more than 6 month, select)
xyz     wi      3/2/2019     1           (select)
xyz     wi      10/23/2019   2           (compare with 1st , more than 6 month , select)
xyz     wi      11/27/2019   3           (compare with 2nd, less than 6 month , filter out)
xyz     msw     2/21/2019    1            (select)
xyz     msw     2/20/2020    2           (compare with 1st , more than 6 month , select)
```

As per above data , i need to write a logic for each email and brand , to filter out response no which are within 6 months from previous selected response startdate. for ex. for **email abc  and brand wi** , i have 1st response (response no 1) on 4/1/2019 , 2nd response is on 9/24/2019, (5 months from 1st) , so i need to filter it out , next 3rd response is 11/22/2019 , (more than 6 months from 1st response) so dont filter out. if 2nd response would have been 6 months later than 1st , i need to avoid filtering it and then 3rd response will have to be compared with 2nd instead of 1st
 Basically , checking condition to filter should be between current response date and previous response date which was not filtered out  per email per brand

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are expecting the following output yes ?

[image]

So from a SQL point of view, I did the following ( it can be solved in other ways too ):

```
Create Table DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST (
  email varchar(255),
  brand varchar(4),  
  startdate date, 
  response_no numeric(10,0)
); 

Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('abc', 'wi', '2019-04-01', 1);         
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('abc', 'wi', '2019-09-04', 2);         
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('abc', 'wi', '2019-11-22', 3);         
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('xyz', 'wi', '2019-03-02', 1);         
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('xyz', 'wi', '2019-10-23', 2);         
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('xyz', 'wi', '2019-11-27', 3);         
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('xyz', 'msw', '2019-02-21', 1);          
Insert Into DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST VALUES('xyz', 'msw', '2020-02-20', 2);
```

SQL:

```
Select SRC.EMAIL, 
       SRC.BRAND,
       SRC.STARTDATE
From 
(
Select EMAIL, 
       BRAND,
       STARTDATE,
       lag(STARTDATE) over (partition by EMAIL, BRAND order by STARTDATE) as PREV_DATE,
       Case When PREV_DATE Is Null Then -1 Else (-1*(datediff(month,STARTDATE,PREV_DATE))) End as DATE_DIFF_MTH, 
       Case When PREV_DATE Is Null Then '1949-01-01'
            Else Case When (-1*(datediff(month,STARTDATE,PREV_DATE))) < 6 
                      Then lead(STARTDATE) over (partition by EMAIL, BRAND order by STARTDATE)
                      Else STARTDATE End End as DATE_TO_CONSIDER
From DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST
Order By 1,2  
) P
Inner Join DB_NM.SCHEMA_NM.TEST SRC ON SRC.STARTDATE = P.DATE_TO_CONSIDER
Where P.PREV_DATE IS NOT NULL
Order BY 1,2
```

As I said there are other ways to solve this. Hope this helps!

Thanks

Comment: Expected output is                                      
abc wi 2019-04-01 1
abc wi 2019-11-22 3
xyz wi 2019-03-02 1
xyz  wi 2019-10-23 2
xyz msw 2019-02-21 1
xyz msw 2020-02-20 2

Comment: Oh i think i misunderstood your question. let me re-write the sql